# Как в dataframe pandas данные из string перевести в dict

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Всем привет.

У меня есть такая строка в DataFrame:

'[{"name":"Безопасность","values":["Антипробуксовочная система (ASR)","Система стабилизации (ESP)","Подушка безопасности водителя","Крепление детского кресла (задний ряд) ISOFIX","Подушки безопасности оконные (шторки)","Подушка безопасности пассажира","Подушки безопасности боковые задние","Подушки безопасности боковые","Датчик давления в шинах","Антиблокировочная система (ABS)","Блокировка замков задних дверей","Подушка безопасности для защиты коленей водителя"]},{"name":"Комфорт","values":["Система «старт-стоп»","Электростеклоподъёмники передние","Мультифункциональное рулевое колесо","Прикуриватель и пепельница","Бортовой компьютер","Усилитель руля","Электропривод зеркал","Электростеклоподъёмники задние","Парктроник передний","Регулировка руля по вылету","Климат-контроль 2-зонный","Электроскладывание зеркал","Парктроник задний"]},{"name":"Мультимедиа","values":["AUX","USB","Аудиосистема","Bluetooth"]},{"name":"Обзор","values":["Датчик света","Автоматический корректор фар","Омыватель фар","Датчик дождя","Электрообогрев боковых зеркал","Светодиодные фары"]},{"name":"Салон","values":["Регулировка передних сидений по высоте","Передний центральный подлокотник","Складывающееся заднее сиденье","Электрорегулировка передних сидений","Тёмный салон","Кожа (Материал салона)","Обогрев рулевого колеса","Подогрев передних сидений","Отделка кожей рулевого колеса"]},{"name":"Защита от угона","values":["Центральный замок","Иммобилайзер"]}]'

оно именно как string идет. а мне нужно перевести это в dict

и не могу сообразить как это сделать.

подскажите, пожалуйста, решение

Comment: Кратко: никак, pandas не поддерживает такой тип для колонок   https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Нашел решение:

import json

df['equipment'] = [{"name":"Безопасность","values":["Антипробуксовочная система (ASR)","Система стабилизации (ESP)","Подушка безопасности водителя","Крепление детского кресла (задний ряд) ISOFIX","Подушки безопасности оконные (шторки)","Подушка безопасности пассажира","Подушки безопасности боковые задние","Подушки безопасности боковые","Датчик давления в шинах","Антиблокировочная система (ABS)","Блокировка замков задних дверей","Подушка безопасности для защиты коленей водителя"]},{"name":"Комфорт","values":["Система «старт-стоп»","Электростеклоподъёмники передние","Мультифункциональное рулевое колесо","Прикуриватель и пепельница","Бортовой компьютер","Усилитель руля","Электропривод зеркал","Электростеклоподъёмники задние","Парктроник передний","Регулировка руля по вылету","Климат-контроль 2-зонный","Электроскладывание зеркал","Парктроник задний"]},{"name":"Мультимедиа","values":["AUX","USB","Аудиосистема","Bluetooth"]},{"name":"Обзор","values":["Датчик света","Автоматический корректор фар","Омыватель фар","Датчик дождя","Электрообогрев боковых зеркал","Светодиодные фары"]},{"name":"Салон","values":["Регулировка передних сидений по высоте","Передний центральный подлокотник","Складывающееся заднее сиденье","Электрорегулировка передних сидений","Тёмный салон","Кожа (Материал салона)","Обогрев рулевого колеса","Подогрев передних сидений","Отделка кожей рулевого колеса"]},{"name":"Защита от угона","values":["Центральный замок","Иммобилайзер"]}]

data = json.loads(df['equipment'])
```